# Why don't my watched tags stick in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have a Stack Overflow for Teams site for our company that we've been getting a lot of good out of, but we found that when we set up tags to watch, they don't "stick" - i.e., when you go back to the home page of the team S.O., it still shows empty "Watched Tags on XYZ" and "Ignored Tags" sidebar widgets.

After a user in our team S.O. reported their experience I replicated it. I added the `java` tag to "watched" and the `ruby` tag to "ignored". I do see them show up in the sidebar:

[image]

But when I reload the home page of our team S.O., I see the empty widgets:

[image]

Comment: Can you retest? Because I can no longer repro after a network wide bugfix was deployed.

Comment: Still happening. But I don't see it happening on this site (meta SO).

Comment: I can repro again, it gives me a 404 error in the console on `/c/[team]/users/tags/subscribe`

Comment: I'm gonna migrate this question to MSO so it can be more easily seen by the Teams dev team.

Comment: I have the fix in review right now.  We disabled a bunch of routes in the /users controller that don't apply to teams (like settings pages), and /users/save-preference got caught up in that, breaking the "Add" button.  @rene's error on /users/tags/subscribe is probably the result of adding a non-existent tag and then trying to update its frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed.

The way Teams is designed, routes inside a team hit mostly the same logic as routes outside of a team.  As such, the users controller had a bunch of routes that while not exposed as links, still existed but were not intended to be used and could provide a somewhat broken experience.  To clean that up, we made those unneeded routes 404 inside Teams.

Unfortunately, one route that was caught up in that which shouldn't have been is `/users/save-preference`, the route that's hit when you add a watched tag from the sidebar.

I've updated `/users/save-preference` to work in Teams again. I also updated the UI to show an error message if the request itself fails, similar to the one you see when adding a tag that doesn't exist in the team.  That way it'll be more obvious when we break it again in the future.

Watching a tag from the popover or on a tag search page was still working as expected, as was updating the frequency for watched tags that exist in the Team.

Comment: I can confirm this works for me now.

Comment: Confirming it works in our S.O. for Teams site. Thanks!